# Spring как добавить новый объект в контекст

Tags: spring, spring-boot, zuul

Есть у меня определенный фильтр, который достает и формирует сущность `UserState` как можно добавить эту сущность в контекст что бы я мог использовать ее в следующих фильтрах а не формировал заново? Или есть какие то другие практики для передачи объекта между фильтрами?

```
public class AuthFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER - 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        String requestURI = context.getRequest().getRequestURI();
        for (String authPath : authPaths) {
            if (requestURI.contains(authPath)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {

        try {
            UserState userState = authService.getUserData();

            DefaultListableBeanFactory context = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

            GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            beanDefinition.setBeanClass(UserState.class);
            beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(new MutablePropertyValues() {
                {
                    add("user", userState);
                }
            });
            context.registerBeanDefinition("userState", beanDefinition);
        } catch (UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
            if (e.getUndeclaredThrowable().getClass() == UnauthorizedException.class) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException(e.getMessage());
            }

            if (e.getUndeclaredThrowable().getClass() == ForbiddenException.class) {
                throw new ForbiddenException(e.getMessage(), "The user is not allowed to make this request");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет необходимости работать с контекстом напрямую. 
Можно отдать создание на откуп Спрингу и в фильтре его только заполнять. Или Создавать спрингом объект - хранилище объектов и в фильтрах докидывать в него нужные.  Если это нужно привязывать к сессии то работать через сессионный бин.

```
public class UserStateHolder {

    UserState userState; 

    public UserState getUserState() {
        return this.userState;
    }

    public void setUserState(UserState userState) {
        this.userState = userState;;
    }

}

@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MySessionProxy {

    private UserStateHolder userStateHolder = new UserStateHolder();

    public UserStateHolder getUserStateHolder() {
        return userStateHolder;
    }

}

public class AuthFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MySessionProxy mySessionProxy;
....................................................
    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {
         .................................
         mySessionProxy.getUserStateHolder().setUserState(userState);
    }
}
```